# Hosmer-Lemeshow recommendations

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value, inference, hosmer-lemeshow-test

[image]

During lectures I came across following statement:

> If you want Hosmer-Lemeshow test to be valid, number of expected events ($E_1g$) should be >5 in most of $g$ groups

Then after few lectures, lecturer said:

> If you want Hosmer-Lemeshow test to be valid, number of expected events($E_1g$) and non-events ($E_0g$) should be >5 in 80% of cells.

I googled whole internet, read 3 most popular books about logistic regression and still can find answer about which version is correct.

The question is: which recommendation for Hosmer-Lemeshow test is proper one? Or maybe you know another one and can give some papers about it?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but worth reading nonetheless: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/207512/124848

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hosmer and Lemeshow answered this question in 1980 in their paper *Sample size requirements for studies estimating odds ratios or relative risks* to be find [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/sim.4780070705). In further works they refer to this paper.

The values stated in your lecture refer to the recommendations by [William G. Cochran](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/3001616.pdf?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), first published 1954  in his paper *Some Methods for Strengthening the Common $\chi^2$ Tests*. His works refers to the pearson-chi-squared-test. These assumptations are cited often for any chi-squared statistics.