# How to Redress an Invalid Logistic Regression

Tags: logistic, sampling, residuals, goodness-of-fit

Recently I ran a logistic regression model using the census data [here](https://www.hcp.ma/Recensement-General-de-la-Population-et-de-l-Habitat-RGPH-2014_a2945.html). The model attempts to assess the relationship between female labor force participation and other variables. Here is the code I used to create the model:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(stargazer)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(dplyr)
library(haven)
library(tidyr)
    
individu <- read_dta("Le fichier Individu en format STATA.dta")
    
newdata <- individu %>% filter(sexe==2 & AGE5>=25) %>% 
      select(AGE5, TY_ACT, NIV_ET_AGR, E_MAT, mil, reg, ENF_VIV) %>% 
      rename_all(funs(c("Age","Act","Edu","Mar","Loc","Reg","Kid"))) %>% 
mutate(across(c("Edu","Mar","Loc"), as_factor)) %>% 
mutate(Kid = ifelse(is.na(Kid), 0, Kid)) %>% 
mutate(Act = ifelse(Act == 0, 1, 0)) %>% 
mutate(Edu = fct_drop(Edu)) %>% 
mutate(Mar = fct_drop(Mar)) %>% 
mutate(Loc = fct_drop(Loc)) %>% 
na.omit()
      
newdata$Edu <- recode_factor(newdata$Edu, 
     "Aucun niveau d'études" = "No Education", 
     "Préscolaire" = "Preschool", 
     "Primaire" = "Primary Sch.", 
     "Secondaire collégial" = "Middle Sch.", 
     "Secondaire qualifiant" = "High Sch.", 
     "Supérieur" = "University")
        
newdata$Mar <- recode_factor(newdata$Mar, "Célibataire" = "Single",
                                 "Marié" = "Married",
                                 "Divorcé" = "Divorced",
                                 "Veuf" = "Widow")
    
newdata$Loc <- recode_factor(newdata$Loc, "Urbain" = "Urban")
    
# Run the general model
    
main_model <- glm(Act ~ Age + I(Age^2) + Edu + Mar + Kid + Loc,
                      family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
                      data = newdata)
```

Which gave me the following results:

```r
> summary(main_model)
    
    Call:
    glm(formula = Act ~ Age + I(Age^2) + Edu + Mar + Kid + Loc, 
        family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
        data = newdata)
    
    Deviance Residuals: 
        Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
    -2.0413  -0.5466  -0.3897  -0.2084   3.6565  
    
    Coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error  z value Pr(>|z|)    
    (Intercept)     -5.216e+00  4.054e-02 -128.665  < 2e-16 ***
    Age              2.211e-01  1.958e-03  112.901  < 2e-16 ***
    I(Age^2)        -2.677e-03  2.301e-05 -116.307  < 2e-16 ***
    EduPreschool    -5.677e-02  3.970e-02   -1.430   0.1528    
    EduPrimary Sch.  2.145e-02  9.476e-03    2.263   0.0236 *  
    EduMiddle Sch.   2.743e-01  1.110e-02   24.711  < 2e-16 ***
    EduHigh Sch.     1.018e+00  1.032e-02   98.576  < 2e-16 ***
    EduUniversity    1.971e+00  1.087e-02  181.393  < 2e-16 ***
    MarMarried      -7.747e-01  9.175e-03  -84.431  < 2e-16 ***
    MarDivorced      6.336e-01  1.318e-02   48.081  < 2e-16 ***
    MarWidow         1.165e-01  1.452e-02    8.026 1.01e-15 ***
    Kid             -1.781e-01  2.245e-03  -79.342  < 2e-16 ***
    LocRural        -4.381e-01  8.251e-03  -53.105  < 2e-16 ***
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
    
    (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
    
        Null deviance: 809064  on 913577  degrees of freedom
    Residual deviance: 654932  on 913565  degrees of freedom
    AIC: 654958
    
    Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6
```

However, when I followed the steps in this [website](https://rpubs.com/benhorvath/logistic_regression) to assess the statistical validity of my model, I found results suggesting that my model is not statistically very sound:

```r
# Hosmer-Lemeshow Test: The p.value should be high.
    > 
> ResourceSelection::hoslem.test(newdata$Act, fitted(main_model))
    
        Hosmer and Lemeshow goodness of fit (GOF) test
    
    data:  newdata$Act, fitted(main_model)
    X-squared = 2414.8, df = 8, p-value < 2.2e-16
        
    > # Pseudo R^2: this should be close to 1, ideally.
    > 
    > DescTools::PseudoR2(main_model, which = 'Nagelkerke')
    Nagelkerke 
     0.2642365 
    
    > # Residuals plot
    > 
    > dev_res <- residuals(main_model, type='deviance')
    
    > dev_res_std <- residuals(main_model, type='deviance') / 
           sqrt(1 - hatvalues(main_model))
    
    > pearson_res <- residuals(main_model, type='pearson')
    
    > pearson_res_std <- residuals(main_model, type='pearson') / 
    sqrt(1 - hatvalues(main_model))
    
    > par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
    
    > plot(density(pearson_res), main='Deviance (red) v. Pearson 
        Residuals')
    
    > lines(density(dev_res), col='red')
    
    > plot(density(pearson_res_std), main='Deviance Standardized (red) v.\n Pearson Standardized Residuals')
    
    > lines(density(dev_res_std), col='red')
```

[image]

Therefore I would like to know: is this because my response variable `Act` is not balanced (0: 84%, 1: 16%)? If so, how do I extract a sample that is balanced as per the variable `Act`, but also balanced by region. Any help would be very much appreciated.

PS: I wanted to use the [BalancedSampling](http://www.antongrafstrom.se/balancedsampling/) library, it can create a balanced sample by region, but I don't think it will guarantee the proportions of `Act` will be balanced.

### EDIT 0:

I created a balanced sample, i.e. one with 100,000 observations with `Act==0`, and 100,000 observations with `Act==1`. The problem persists, and the deviance graph looks like this:
[image]

### EDIT 1:

Following the [links](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169438/evaluating-logistic-regression-and-interpretation-of-hosmer-lemeshow-goodness-of/207512#207512) in the first comment,
which argue against the use of `R^2` and Hosmer-Lemeshow test to measure the goodness-of-fit, and propose their own measures instead, I installed the `rms` package to check the goodness of fit as measured by their `resid` function. It gave me the following results:

```r
> lrm_one <- lrm(formula = Act ~ Age + AgeSq + Edu + Mar + Kid + 
                     Loc, data = newdata, y = TRUE, x = TRUE)
> resid(lrm_one, "gof")
Sum of squared errors     Expected value|H0                    SD                     Z                     P 
             1.004713e+05          1.003799e+05          2.218171e+01          4.121127e+00          3.770231e-05
```

The p.value is very small and the model is not good. Therefore it is clear that the problem is in my model, not in how I measure the goodness of fit. The residuals plots generated by `rms` are also similar to the ones above.

Comment: Have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/273966/logistic-regression-with-poor-goodness-of-fit-hosmer-lemeshow  and  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169438/evaluating-logistic-regression-and-interpretation-of-hosmer-lemeshow-goodness-of/207512#207512

Comment: I'm not seeing why you think your model is poor in what you've presented.  Your comment in the code - that the pseudo-R^2 should be close to 1 - seems to indicate that you believe you should be able to predict whether a given individual is in the labor force or not with a very high degree of accuracy; this seems overly optimistic to me, to say the least.

Comment: @jbowman I think the Pseudo-r^2 is too low. I am trying to submit a paper to a respected journal, and I believe the reviewers will ask about the statistical validity of my model (goodness of fit + predictive ability).

Comment: 1) Predictive performance of the regressions in many academic articles (even in top journals) can be terrible. I have seen linear regressions with $R^2\approx 0.01$, maybe lower. $//$ 2) Pseudo $R^2$ in logistic regressions play by different rules, and for McFadden's pseudo of $R^2$, McFadden himself claimed that $0.2$ to $0.4$ would qualify as outstanding performance.

Comment: You might want to read this article: https://thestatsgeek.com/2014/02/08/r-squared-in-logistic-regression/ for a bit of insight on McFadden's $R^2$.  The money quote:  "the conclusion I draw is that one should really not be surprised if, from a fitted logistic regression McFadden’s R2 is not particularly large – we need extremely strong predictors in order for it to get close to 1."  In his simulations, even a 90% accuracy only got an $R^2 = 0.55$.

Comment: You seem to have a very large sample, which could support a larger model. Effects of `age` could well be non-linear, so maybe represent it with a spline? Maybe some interactions make sense? Can you show us some plot of residuals versus age?

Comment: A couple of other (possible) issues with your analysis: You fill in "unknown number of children" with 0. This is incorrect unless the documentation explicitly says what "missing" means "no children". And then you drop all rows with any missing data remaining, which can introduce bias. To add to @kjetilbhalvorsen, you can spline number of children as well as age (ideally after coming up with a more appropriate way to handle missing data).

Comment: Thank you for the remarks @dipetkov, I will rewrite the code differently and see what happens.